# Upload a file to Azure blob storage using plupload

Tags: azure-blob-storage, plupload

I want to upload a file to Azure blob storage using plupload. I could not find any documentation on how this can be done. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage J[avaScript Client Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/tree/master/browser) for Browsers can help you. Here is a [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-javascript-client-libraries)

Comment: I have already integrated my application with plupload. Is there any way that I can upload using [plupload](https://www.plupload.com/) only.

Comment: When possible it is always preferable to use native SDK over third party libraries.